# Check to see if a value is within a range?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in a `data.table` format that looks as such:

```
ID     time.s     time.e
1       1         2
2       1         4
3       2         3
4       2         4
```

I want to check to see if the value 1 is within `time.s` and `time.e` so that the end result would look like

```
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

How would I go about this? I have tried to use

```
 a[1 %in% seq(time.s, time.e)]
```

But all I get is all TRUE values. Any recommendations?

Comment: @scoa. This is actually a data.table

Comment: @akash87 sorry then ; but you should mention it in the question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the values of `ID` are unique:

```
DT[, list(OK = 1 %in% seq(time.s, time.e)), by = ID]
```

giving;

```
   ID    OK
1:  1  TRUE
2:  2  TRUE
3:  3 FALSE
4:  4 FALSE
```

Comment: This unfortunately only works with discrete (unitary? I'm missing the word here but I hope the meaning comes through) values of time... e.g. 2 is in seq(1, 3) but 2.2 is not. And of course one can specify the step of seq() but that only solves this much..

Answer (score 15):

Also, this works:

```
with(dat, time.s <= 1 & time.e >= 1)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a `dplyr` option in case anybody stumbles on this question:

```
library(dplyr)
value = 1
df %>% 
  mutate(ok = value >= time.s & value <= time.e)

  ID time.s time.e    ok
1  1      1      2  TRUE
2  2      1      4  TRUE
3  3      2      3 FALSE
4  4      2      4 FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for the dplyr answer, it's so simple but I was stuck in a base-R mindset while trying to do this on a project.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding to the tools that could be used to this, another being `data.table::between`:

```
data.frame <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
                         time.s = c(1,1,2,2),
                         time.e = c(2,4,3,4))

data.table::between(1, data.frame$time.s, data.frame$time.e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one.

```
library(TeachingDemos)
a[time.s %<=% 1 %<=% time.e]
```

It's probably overkill to load a library for that, but the syntax is quite intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer with base r:

```
data.frame <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
                         time.s = c(1,1,2,2),
                         time.e = c(2,4,3,4))

data.frame$OK<-data.frame$ID%in%c(data.frame$time.s:data.frame$time.e)

data.frame
  ID time.s time.e    OK
1  1      1      2  TRUE
2  2      1      4  TRUE
3  3      2      3 FALSE
4  4      2      4 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the function dplyr::between(x,left, right)
[see here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-numeric-value-falls-between-a-range-in-r-programming-between-function/)