# Check whether one integer is within specific range in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a simple way to evaluate a range and check if an integer is within that range?

Other than this post [Check to see if a value is within a range in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683444/check-to-see-if-a-value-is-within-a-range-in-r) I did not find other relevant ones.

Example

```
range <- cut(rep(1,5),4) # Create intervals
range.test <- range[2]
# Now I want to check whether integer 1L is within the range.test （Of course it is）
Code comes here.
```

I tried to use `findInterval` and also convert the `range.test` into vector, or use `seq`, `inrange`or other functions but failed.

As all the analysis is based on `data.table`, and this part of analysis forms part of whole practice of which the output is preferred to be one data.table, so I put tag `data.table` to make sure the consistency.

**EDIT**

The whole picture in the context of `data.table`.

```
dt <- data.table(structure(list(Time = c("2016-01-04 09:05:06", "2016-01-04 09:20:00","2016-01-04 09:30:00", "2016-01-04 09:30:01", "2016-01-04 09:30:02","2016-01-04 09:30:05", "2016-01-04 09:30:06", "2016-01-04 09:31:35","2016-01-04 09:31:38", "2016-01-04 09:32:33"), Price = c(105,104.1, 104.1, 103.9, 104.1, 104, 104.1, 104.1, 104.1, 104), Volume = c(9500L,23500L, 18500L, 12500L, 16118L, 13000L, 2500L, 300L, 500L, 500L), Flag = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Ticker = c("0001","0001", "0001", "0001", "0001", "0001", "0001", "0001", "0001","0001")), .Names = c("Time", "Price", "Volume", "Flag", "Ticker"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L)))
```

```
                   Time Price Volume Flag Ticker
 1: 2016-01-04 09:05:06 105.0   9500    1   0001
 2: 2016-01-04 09:20:00 104.1  23500    0   0001
 3: 2016-01-04 09:30:00 104.1  18500    1   0001
 4: 2016-01-04 09:30:01 103.9  12500    0   0001
 5: 2016-01-04 09:30:02 104.1  16118    1   0001
 6: 2016-01-04 09:30:05 104.0  13000    0   0001
 7: 2016-01-04 09:30:06 104.1   2500    1   0001
 8: 2016-01-04 09:30:07 104.1   1500    1   0001
 9: 2016-01-04 09:30:08 104.3    500    1   0001
10: 2016-01-04 09:30:10 104.0   1000    0   0001
11: 2016-01-04 09:30:11 103.9   1000    0   0001
12: 2016-01-04 09:30:15 104.0   3500    1   0001
13: 2016-01-04 09:30:17 104.3   2000    1   0001
14: 2016-01-04 09:30:19 104.3   1500    1   0001
15: 2016-01-04 09:30:20 104.4    500    1   0001
16: 2016-01-04 09:30:21 104.4   1500    1   0001
17: 2016-01-04 09:30:22 104.4   1000    1   0001
18: 2016-01-04 09:30:24 104.4   1500    1   0001
19: 2016-01-04 09:30:25 104.0   2000    0   0001
20: 2016-01-04 09:30:27 104.1   3500    1   0001
21: 2016-01-04 09:30:35 104.0    500    0   0001
22: 2016-01-04 09:31:14 104.1   5000    1   0001
23: 2016-01-04 09:31:15 104.1    500    1   0001
24: 2016-01-04 09:31:18 104.1   2500    1   0001
25: 2016-01-04 09:31:25 104.1   3000    1   0001
26: 2016-01-04 09:31:29 104.0   2000    0   0001
27: 2016-01-04 09:31:30 104.1    500    1   0001
28: 2016-01-04 09:31:35 104.1    300    1   0001
29: 2016-01-04 09:31:38 104.1    500    1   0001
30: 2016-01-04 09:32:33 104.0    500    0   0001
```

```
# First get the distribution of the Volume
    distribution <- dt[Flag == 1, sum(Volume), by = cut(Price, 5)][, percentage := list(V1/sum(V1))]
# Get the max range bin
Max_range <- distribution[which.max(percentage), cut]
# Get the Closing price
Closing_price <- dt[.N, Price]
# Check whether the closing price is in the Max_range
Code comes here[?????]
```

So here comes the question: for specific `Ticker`, how to check whether the closing price is within the specific range? Just a `True` or `False` is needed. If the `closing_price` is within the `Max_range`, the corresponding `Signal` would be `True`, otherwise it would be `False`.

**EDIT 2**

Added the desired output

The desired output

```
   Ticker Signal
1:   0001   False
```

So I would like to create one function to check whether the Signal is `True` or `False` and then update in the data.table.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The way you are defining intervals just creates the 'intervals' as strings, levels of a factor. The input to `findInterval` for interval is a non-decreasing vector of numbers.

Comment: If you want a `data.table`-tested answer, you should post code that constructs a useful test case.

Comment: hello, @Naumz, I edited the original post to make it clear. Could you please provide any hints? Thanks!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I added the desired output in the post. Could you please take a look. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bigchao is `ticker` the stock code?

Comment: @Aramis7d, yes, it is the stock code. could you provide some ideas thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

So do I understand correctly that you want to find for each ticker (001,002 etc) if there is a value that falls outside a given range?

If that's the issue you could use group_by function from dplyr and a logical expression:

```
group_by(dt,Ticker) %>%
   summarise(Signal=any(with(.,Price>max_price & Price<min_price)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `range.test` object is a factor variable with `levels(range.test)`:

```
levels(range.test)
[1] "(0.999,0.9995]" "(0.9995,1]"     "(1,1.0005]"     "(1.0005,1.001]"
```

When you passed it to findInterval as the second argument it was coerced to the numeric value of 2, so this was the result:

```
> findInterval(1,2)
[1] 0
```

Which was what was supposed to happen because 1 is less than 2. If you really want a sequence of numeric values ranging from 0.999 to 1.001 with 5 values you would use seq:

```
> seq( 0.999,  1.001, length=5)
[1] 0.9990 0.9995 1.0000 1.0005 1.0010
```

You could then test in which interval of that vector the number 1.000 would lie:

```
> findInterval( 1, seq( 0.999,  1.001, length=5) )
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @42-, I've made update to the original post to make it clear. Could you please provide any instructions? Many thanks!